# Implementation of a type-safe generic dynamic array in C

Tags: beginner, c, type-safety

I'm new to C and was trying to write a generic dynamic array which is type safe. I'm not sure if I pulled it off in the best way possible though.

dynarray.h:

```c
#ifndef h_DynArray
#define h_DynArray

#define DYNAMIC_ARR_SIZE 10 // Default size for dynamic arrays
#define DYNAMIC_ARR_GROWTHRATE 2 //Growthrate for dynamic arrays

#define DYNAMIC_ARR_FREE_ON_ERROR 1
#define DYNAMIC_ARR_KEEP_ON_ERROR 0

struct DynArray_Options
{
    char freeOnError; // If set, will free the contents of the array when an error is caught, otherwise the contents remain
} DynArray_Options;

struct $DynArray
{
    size_t size; // Number of elements in array
    size_t capacity; // Capacity of array
    unsigned char* data; // Pointer to data
    struct DynArray_Options options; // Array options

    size_t typeSize; // sizeof(type)
};

void $DynArray_Create(struct $DynArray* arr, size_t typeSize);
void $DynArray_Free(struct $DynArray* arr);
void $DynArray_EmptyPush(struct $DynArray* arr);
void $DynArray_Push(struct $DynArray* arr, void* value);
void $DynArray_Pop(struct $DynArray* arr);
void $DynArray_RemoveAt(struct $DynArray* arr, size_t index);
void $DynArray_Shrink(struct $DynArray* arr);
void $DynArray_Reserve(struct $DynArray* arr, size_t size);

/*
* Defines a DynArray of type(tag).
*/
#define DynArray(tag) DynArray$##tag

/*
* Utility macros for getting functions for type(tag).
*/

#define DynArray_ReinterpretCast(tag) DynArray$##tag##_ReinterpretCast
#define DynArray_Create(tag) DynArray$##tag##_Create
#define DynArray_Free(tag) DynArray$##tag##_Free
#define DynArray_EmptyPush(tag) DynArray$##tag##_EmptyPush
#define DynArray_Push(tag) DynArray$##tag##_Push
#define DynArray_Pop(tag) DynArray$##tag##_Pop
#define DynArray_RemoveAt(tag) DynArray$##tag##_RemoveAt
#define DynArray_Shrink(tag) DynArray$##tag##_Shrink 
#define DynArray_Reserve(tag) DynArray$##tag##_Reserve

#define DynArray_Decl(type, tag) \
$DynArray_Decl_Type(type, tag) \
static inline void DynArray$##tag##_Create(struct DynArray(tag)* arr) \
{ \
    $DynArray_Create(&arr->$arr, sizeof(type)); \
} \
$DynArray_Decl_Func(type, tag) \
$DynArray_Decl_Func_Push(type, tag)

#define $DynArray_Decl_Type(type, tag) \
struct DynArray(tag) \
{ \
    union \
    { \
        struct $DynArray $arr; \
        struct \
        {  \
            size_t size; \
            size_t capacity; \
            type* values; \
            struct DynArray_Options options; \
        }; \
    }; \
};

#define $DynArray_Decl_Func(type, tag) \
static inline struct DynArray(tag) DynArray$##tag##_ReinterpretCast(void* arr) \
{ \
    struct DynArray(tag) dst; \
    memcpy(&dst, arr, sizeof dst); \
    return dst; \
} \
static inline void DynArray$##tag##_Free(struct DynArray(tag)* arr) \
{ \
    $DynArray_Free(&arr->$arr); \
} \
static inline void DynArray$##tag##_EmptyPush(struct DynArray(tag)* arr) \
{ \
    $DynArray_EmptyPush(&arr->$arr); \
} \
static inline void DynArray$##tag##_Pop(struct DynArray(tag)* arr) \
{ \
    $DynArray_Pop(&arr->$arr); \
} \
static inline void DynArray$##tag##_RemoveAt(struct DynArray(tag)* arr, size_t index) \
{ \
    $DynArray_RemoveAt(&arr->$arr, index); \
} \
static inline void DynArray$##tag##_Shrink(struct DynArray(tag)* arr) \
{ \
    $DynArray_Shrink(&arr->$arr); \
} \
static inline void DynArray$##tag##_Reserve(struct DynArray(tag)* arr, size_t size) \
{ \
    $DynArray_Reserve(&arr->$arr, size); \
}

#define $DynArray_Decl_Func_Push(type, tag) \
static inline void DynArray$##tag##_Push(struct DynArray(tag)* arr, type value) \
{ \
    $DynArray_Push(&arr->$arr, &value); \
} \

/*
* The following is used to define the "raw" version of DynArray
* which uses a custom Create function to assign sizeof(type).
*/
$DynArray_Decl_Type(unsigned char, raw)
static inline void DynArray$raw_Create(struct DynArray(raw)* arr, size_t typeSize)
{
    $DynArray_Create(&arr->$arr, typeSize);
}
$DynArray_Decl_Func(unsigned char, raw)
static inline void DynArray$raw_Push(struct DynArray(raw)* arr, void* value)
{
    $DynArray_Push(&arr->$arr, value);
}

#endif
```

dynarray.c:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dynarray.h"

void $DynArray_Create(struct $DynArray* arr, size_t typeSize)
{
    arr->data = malloc(typeSize * DYNAMIC_ARR_SIZE);
    arr->size = 0;
    arr->capacity = DYNAMIC_ARR_SIZE;
    arr->typeSize = typeSize;
    arr->options.freeOnError = DYNAMIC_ARR_FREE_ON_ERROR;
}

void $DynArray_Free(struct $DynArray* arr)
{
    free(arr->data);
    arr->data = NULL;
}

inline void $DynArray_ErrorFree(struct $DynArray* arr)
{
    if (arr->options.freeOnError)
    {
        free(arr->data);
        arr->data = NULL;
    }
}

void $DynArray_EmptyPush(struct $DynArray* arr)
{
    if (arr->data)
    {
        if (arr->size == arr->capacity)
        {
            size_t newCapacity = (size_t)(arr->capacity * DYNAMIC_ARR_GROWTHRATE);
            if (newCapacity == arr->capacity) ++newCapacity;
            void* tmp = realloc(arr->data, arr->typeSize * newCapacity);
            if (tmp)
            {
                arr->data = tmp;
                arr->capacity = newCapacity;
                ++arr->size;
            }
            else
            {
                $DynArray_ErrorFree(arr);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ++arr->size;
        }
    }
}

void $DynArray_Push(struct $DynArray* arr, void* value)
{
    $DynArray_EmptyPush(arr);
    if (arr->data) memcpy(arr->data + (arr->size - 1) * arr->typeSize, value, arr->typeSize);
}

void $DynArray_Pop(struct $DynArray* arr)
{
    if (arr->data)
    {
        if (arr->size > 0)
        {
            --arr->size;
        }
    }
}

void $DynArray_RemoveAt(struct $DynArray* arr, size_t index)
{
    if (arr->data)
    {
        if (arr->size > 1 && index > 0 && index < arr->size)
        {
            size_t size = arr->size - 1 - index;
            if (size != 0) memmove(arr->data + index * arr->typeSize, arr->data + (index + 1) * arr->typeSize, size * arr->typeSize);
            --arr->size;
        }
    }
}

void $DynArray_Shrink(struct $DynArray* arr)
{
    if (arr->data)
    {
        size_t newCapacity = arr->size;
        if (newCapacity != arr->capacity)
        {
            void* tmp = realloc(arr->data, arr->typeSize * newCapacity);
            if (tmp)
            {
                arr->data = tmp;
                arr->capacity = newCapacity;
                ++arr->size;
            }
            else
            {
                $DynArray_ErrorFree(arr);
            }
        }
    }
}

void $DynArray_Reserve(struct $DynArray* arr, size_t size)
{
    if (arr->data)
    {
        size_t newCapacity = arr->size + size;
        if (newCapacity > arr->capacity)
        {
            void* tmp = realloc(arr->data, arr->typeSize * newCapacity);
            if (tmp)
            {
                arr->data = tmp;
                arr->capacity = newCapacity;
                arr->size = size;
            }
            else
            {
                $DynArray_ErrorFree(arr);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            arr->size = size;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        void* tmp = malloc(arr->typeSize * size);
        if (tmp)
        {
            arr->data = tmp;
            arr->capacity = size;
            arr->size = size;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```c
DynArray_Decl(int, int) // Declaration outside

int main()
{
    struct DynArray(int) intArr;
    DynArray_Create(int)(&intArr);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        DynArray_Push(int)(&intArr, i);
    }

    printf("size: %i\n", intArr.size);
    printf("%i\n", intArr.values[2]);
}
```

I'm also not too sure if I utilized union properly in the declaration (`$DynArray_Decl_Type`) or if that produces undefined behaviour.

Comment: `$` is not part of the C standard's coding characters.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 4 → 2. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Big task**

OP's goal of "trying to write a generic dynamic array which is type safe." is admirable, but not a good task for someone new to C.

I recommend to start with a *write a generic dynamic array* for `void *`.

Later, research `_Generic`.

**Not so generic**

Approach relies on types not having spaces.

Try `struct DynArray(long long) llArr;`

**Stand-alone failure**

`#include "dynarray.h"` fails as `dynarray.h` requires prior `#include <>`.  Put those in `dynarray.h`.

Use `#include "dynarray.h"` first, before other includes, in `dynarray.c` to test.

**Why 10**

Rather than some magic number 10, Rework to start with size 0.

```
// #define DYNAMIC_ARR_SIZE 10
```

**Allow `$DynArray_Free(NULL)`**

This, like `free(NULL)`, simplifies clean-up

```
void $DynArray_Free(struct $DynArray* arr) {
  if (arr) {
    free(arr->data);
    arr->data = NULL;
  }
}
```

**More reasonable max line length**

```
        // if (size != 0) memmove(arr->data + index * arr->typeSize, arr->data + (index + 1) * arr->typeSize, size * arr->typeSize);
```

vs.

```
        if (size != 0) {
          memmove(arr->data + index * arr->typeSize, 
              arr->data + (index + 1) * arr->typeSize,
              size * arr->typeSize);
        }
```

**$ is not part of the standard C coding languages**

`$` not needed anyways.  Consider dropping it.

**Unneeded `if()`**

In `$DynArray_Reserve()`, code starts with unneeded `if (arr->data)` test.  `realloc(NULL, ...)` is OK.

> If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the specified size.

**Uniform naming**

Rather than `DYNAMIC_ARR_...`, match `DYNARRAY_...`.

Other than that, *very good* naming scheme.

**Allow pushing `const` data**

```
// void $DynArray_Push(struct $DynArray* arr, void* value)
void $DynArray_Push(struct $DynArray* arr, const void* value)
```

**Not always an error**

`$DynArray_Shrink()` calls `$DynArray_ErrorFree(arr)` even if `arr->size == 0`.

**Bug??**

In `$DynArray_Shrink()`, code has `++arr->size;`.  Maybe `--arr->size;`?

**Pedantic: check overflow**

```
// Add
if (arr->capacity > SIZE_MAX/DYNAMIC_ARR_GROWTHRATE) Handle_Error();
size_t newCapacity = (size_t)(arr->capacity * DYNAMIC_ARR_GROWTHRATE);
```

**Use correct specifier**

I also suspect code was not compiled with all warnings enabled.  Save time, enabled them all.

```
// printf("size: %i\n", intArr.size);
printf("size: %zu\n", intArr.size);
```

**[Info hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)**

Consider only *declaring* `struct $DynArray` in `dynarry.h` and putting the *definition* in `dynarray.c`.  User need not see the members.  Create access functions if member access needed.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful, however in the case of types having spaces such as in `long long`, is this not covered by the code using a `tag` for its types? For example: `DynArray_Decl(long long, longlong)` then when using it, use `struct DynArray(longlong)`

Comment: Also yes there is a bug in the shrink function, thanks for pointing that out haha, there should be no modification to `arr->size`. Good catch!

Comment: Also, just had a very quick look at _Generic, but I'm not sure how it would work to allow for user-defined types.

Comment: @name Re: `DynArray_Decl`.  The .h file provides scant info on its usage.  Sample code also lacks detail with  `DynArray_Decl(int, int)`.  AFAIK, one should code `DynArray_Decl(long long, long long)`.  Do not relay on user access to the *.c file to understand how to this function set.  More documentation in the .h file is deserved.

Comment: @name Does not `main()` demo a failed _type safe_? `struct DynArray(int) intArr; ... 
        DynArray_Push(int)(&intArr, i /* which is a size_t and not int */);`?

Comment: You are completely right, the demo does fail type safe. I'll edit to fix it haha.

Comment: In visual studio I don't get a compiler warning / error for using `size_t` instead of `int`, I either have suppressed warnings or there is an implicit conversion I'm unaware of.

Comment: I'll keep documentation on usage in mind, would you like to add that to your answer?

Comment: @name the goal "type-safe generic dynamic array" has 3  parts; "type-safe", "generic",  "dynamic array".  IMO start docs and code with "dynamic array" and then proceed to "generic", then "type-safe".  You have selected a quite ambitious task here.